# Greatest date from list of date

Tags: sql, date

I have this simple data base:

7/2/2013

7/13/2013

I write a simple SQL statement to select the greatest date from a list of date. I try to use the (max function) as follow:

```
select max([P_Date]) from [BalDB].[dbo].[tab_Product]
```

The result was incorrect; it gives me the smallest date not the greatest as follow:

```
7/2/2013
```

So please help me to know what is the problem in my SQL statement and how can I solve it
Problem: Get the greatest date from a list of date or compare it with local date and take the greater!!

Comment: What is the type of that column?  It looks like `max()` is treating it like a character value, not a date value.

Comment: YEAH IT IS nvarchar(50) !!!

Comment: Well then there's the reason.  It's returning the max value correctly based on the type of the data.  The best approach here would be to change the column holding the date to be of type date so that the database engine can optimize it accordingly.  If that's not possible, then the query will have to convert the values into date values on the fly.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR FOR YOUR HELP!! I WILL WORK WITH YOUR ADVANCE :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sql [max](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp) function returns the largest value of the selected column, in your case since your data type is a `nvarchar` the *largest* value is what is alphabetically larger, which in this case is `7/2/2013` (since the "2" is greater then the "1" in "13").

What you need to do is basically what [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) mentioned, either chance the data type of the column or if it isn't feasible then you can cast it in your query as a `datetime`

For example

```
select max(cast([P_Date] as datetime)) from [BalDB].[dbo].[tab_Product]
```

Comment: Helpful way to solve the problem!!
Thank you both @Jack and David for helping me :D

Comment: Is it possible to convert the format of the datetime from:2013-07-13 00:00:00.000 to sort datetime: 2013-07-13????

Comment: Yes, depending on what data base system (and which version) you can either convert it to a date instead of a datetime or you can just format it afterwards to truncate the time part.

Comment: Try using [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with the 3 style.

Comment: Thank you @Jack :It work fine, 

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),max(cast([P_Date] as datetime)),101) from [BalDB].[dbo].[tab_Product]

Answer (score 0):

The max function is making this slower than it needs to be, try this.

```
select top 1 convert(datetime,P_Date) from [BalDB].[dbo].[tab_Product] order by convert(datetime,P_Date) desc
```

Now your dates should be date types, not varchars, but for the sake of querying your data as is, this will work.

Comment: Is MAX() really slower than an ORDER BY plus row limiter? Do you have any proof? They ought to optimize to the same thing (I don't use SQL Server often).

Comment: @Ben I don't thing the OP actually said what data base system they were using. That said I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the format of the datetime from:2013-07-13 00:00:00.000  to sort datetime: 2013-07-13????

Comment: To clarify, if the statement never has to change in the future, to add columns to the select then the performance should be near identical. However if in the future there needs to be a change like adding a column, using max in the statement will degrade performance. Using this wont. So not using max prevents re-writing the whole query if change is needed.

Comment: @AhmedImair just convert to date rather than datetime if you dont want to include time

Comment: @James :( There is Error (Type date is not a defined system type.)
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: What version of MSSQL?

Comment: 10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )

Comment: Weird, date is a valid type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724%28v=sql.100%29.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes

Comment: @James: In my list I have only (datetime and smalldatetime)!! Other like (time, date, datetime2, datetimeoffset) not included in my SQL server!!

Comment: @AhmedImair it depends on the version sql server, note that you can have a later version of the management studio then the version of sql server.

Comment: @Jack:This is one of the drawbacks of Microsoft Company – I hate this way of developing version!!

Comment: @AhmedImair not sure how it's a drawback in this case, it's just that Sql Management studio is backwards compatible.

Comment: @Jack Finally I get it!! 
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),max(cast([P_Date] as datetime)),101) from [BalDB].[dbo].[tab_Product]